# Calculate $\frac{i^2-i^{31}+(4+3i)(5-2i)}{\frac{1}{2}i}$ without a calculator

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I tried:

$$\frac{i^2-i^{31}+(4+3i)(5-2i)}{\frac{1}{2}i} = \\
\frac{-1-(-1)+(4+3i)(5-2i)}{\frac{1}{2}i}= \\
\frac{26+7i}{\frac{1}{2}i} = \\
\frac{52+14i}{i} = \\
\frac{(52+14i)\cdot-i}{i\cdot -i} = \\ \\
14-52i$$

But my book states the solution is $16-50i$. What went wrong?

Comment: $i^{31}=(i^4)^7\cdot i^3=-i$ not $-1$

Comment: $i^30=i^2×i^2×...i^2=-1$

Comment: @sharding4 When i tried calculating that I did $i^{31}=i^{30}\cdot i = (i^{3})^{{10}}\cdot i = (-i)^{10}\cdot i = i\cdot i = -1$ What did I do wrong?

Comment: @sharding4 Nevermind, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Numerator: $-1+i+20-8i+15i+6$, which simplifies to $25+8i$. Can you divide this by $\frac{i}{2}$?